# PyOpenGL, issue with 3D graphics on a screen using glFrustum and glTranslate

Tags: python, opengl, opencv, 3d, projection

Overview:

I am trying to create a 3D application similar to this:

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9kPI7_vhAU.
```

I am using OpenCV2.2, Python2.7 and pyOpenGL.
This can be achieved by [this background maths and code snippet](http://imgur.com/Blg9VeO) where x, y, z are the positions of the viewers eye (as grabbed from a webcam!)

Issue:

When I do this, the object (a cube) that I have rendered becomes stretched along the z axis (into the screen) and I'm not too sure why. It is likened to looking down a very tall skyscraper from above (as opposed to a cube). The cube's position changes very rapidly in the z direction as the z position of the eye changes. [This](http://imgur.com/ccbl9yV) is a frame of the result, it has been stretched!

Code (with bigD's edit):

```
def DrawGLScene():
    #get some parameters for calculating the FRUSTUM
    NEAR_CLIPPING_PLANE = 0.01
    FAR_CLIPPING_PLANE  = 2
    window = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)
    WINDOW_WIDTH = window[2]
    WINDOW_HEIGHT= window[3]

    #do facial detection and get eye co-ordinates
    eye = getEye()

    #clear window
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    #before any projection transformation command comes these 2 lines:
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()

    #transform projection to that of our eye
    glFrustum(NEAR_CLIPPING_PLANE*(-WINDOW_WIDTH /2 - eye[0])/eye[2],
              NEAR_CLIPPING_PLANE*( WINDOW_WIDTH /2 - eye[0])/eye[2],
              NEAR_CLIPPING_PLANE*(-WINDOW_HEIGHT/2 - eye[1])/eye[2],
              NEAR_CLIPPING_PLANE*( WINDOW_HEIGHT/2 - eye[1])/eye[2],
              NEAR_CLIPPING_PLANE, FAR_CLIPPING_PLANE)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslatef(-eye[0],-eye[1],-eye[2])

    drawCube()

    glutSwapBuffers()
```

an example of the data getEye() returns is:

[0.25,0.37,1]   if viewers is has their face near lower left of screen and is 1m away

[-0.5,-0.1,0.5] if viewers is has their face near upper right of screen and is 0.5m away

The cube when drawn has height, width, depth of 2 and its centre at (0,0,0).

I will provide the full code if anyone wants to do a similar project and wants a kickstart or thinks that the issue lies somewhere else than code provided.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting strange results is because of this:

```
glTranslatef(-eye[0],-eye[1],-eye[2])
```

This call should be made after

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
```

Because the projection matrix is ready as it is with your glFrustum call, if you multiply it by a translation matrix that won't make it a perspective projection matrix anymore. The modelview matrix has to describe all world AND camera transformations.

Also bear in mind that if the only transformation you do on your modelview matrix is a translation, then you will always be staring down the negative-Z axis.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Whilst what you said is true, it appears the same answer is produced! I have edited the code above to include your suggestion. I'm absolutely stumped now!

Comment: Ok I think I found another problem:
Your glFrustum() call seems to depend on your eye's world space coordinates. Take a look at this image
http://i.iinfo.cz/r/photos/opengl/opengl_14_1.gif

The glFrustum call really just defines your field of view, aspect ratio, and the limit to how far an object can be until it gets cut off. When looking at that image, picture the frustum being at (0,0,0) and starring down the negative-Z axis. This is in 'camera space' now, so any coordinates in world space have no meaning here because everything's already been transformed by the modelview matrix

Comment: typically, your left/right/top/bottom value would be computed by left|right = +/- near_plane*tan(0.5*fovx)
bottom|top = +/- near_plane*tan(0.5*fovy)
where fovx and fovy are horizontal and vertical fields of view.
Or you can pick a fixed horizontal or vertical field of view and aspect ratio and determine all the planes that way